# Conversation window xaml windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to create a chat window simlair to messanger for the time being now I have managed to get the to and from chat messages working but I am lost on how I would geta  textbox to appear at the end for entry with the same path that I have used on the texblox for the conversation.

```
<Page
        x:Class="Curo.ChatMessage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:Curo"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:helpers="using:Curo.Helpers"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Background="#FFFDFDFD" Foreground="#FF040404">

        <Page.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="ToTemplate">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="ToBubble" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Margin="0" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Grid.Row="0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TextMessage}" x:Name="MainText" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="0" Width="300" FontSize="21.333" Padding="10,5,10,5">

                            </TextBlock>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Opacity="0.8" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Time}" x:Name="timeText" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="0" Padding="10" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                <TextBlock Opacity="0.8" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Status}" x:Name="status" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="0" Padding="10" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                            </Grid>

                        </Grid>
                        <Path Grid.Row="1"  Data="M404,136 L404,149.5 L387.5,134.5 z" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="20" Margin="0,-5,10,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="FromTemplate">
                <Grid x:Name="FromBubble" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Path Grid.Row="0"  Data="M404,136 L404,149.5 L387.5,134.5 z" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="20" Margin="10,2,10,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform Rotation="-179.206"/>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                    <Grid Margin="0" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TextMessage}" x:Name="MainText2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="0" Width="300" FontSize="21.333" Padding="10,5,10,5">

                        </TextBlock>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Opacity="0.8" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Time}" x:Name="timeText2" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="0" Padding="10" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        </Grid>

                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
            <helpers:ChatBubbleSelector x:Key="ChatBubbleTemplateSelector" toBubble="{StaticResource ToTemplate}" fromBubble="{StaticResource FromTemplate}"></helpers:ChatBubbleSelector>
            <TextBox  x:Name="test" Text="test"/>
        </Page.Resources>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="My Chat Window" Margin="10,10,2,0.667" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
            <ListBox Height="450" Background="White" Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" x:Name="myChat" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ChatBubbleTemplateSelector}" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="Black">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
        <Page.BottomAppBar>
            <CommandBar>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="me bubble" x:Name="meClick"  ></AppBarButton>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="you bubble" x:Name="youClick"  ></AppBarButton>
            </CommandBar>
        </Page.BottomAppBar>
```

This is my chat window

[image]

And I want mine to look like the standard one I am not looking to rip off facebook this is just a learning exercise to better my understanding of xaml.

[image]

I tried just adding the textbox at the end but obviously its not showing in pic for some reason. Should I use blend for this?

**Edit**

My Second Attempt of trying

```
  <Grid Margin="0" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding TextMessage}" x:Name="MainText2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="0" Width="300" FontSize="21.333" Padding="10,5,10,5">

                        </TextBlock>


                        <TextBox  x:Name="test" Text="test" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="0" Width="300" FontSize="21.333" Padding="10,5,10,5"></TextBox>
```

As you see puts it over the message bubble.

[image]

Comment: Why you use Grid.Row = 0 for the text box? If you want it below the chat, use Grid.Row="1"

Comment: @Jogy i tried that at that position but its still not displaying

Comment: try this VerticalAlignment="Bottom"

Comment: @thewindev that will only place it below the blue message I am wanting ti below the entire list much same way facebook does. so that it can be the correspondants reply

Comment: <helpers:ChatBubbleSelector x:Key="ChatBubbleTemplateSelector" toBubble="{StaticResource ToTemplate}" fromBubble="{StaticResource FromTemplate}"></helpers:ChatBubbleSelector>     This line of control creating error. would you please let me know about this...? I 'll be very thankful to you

Answer (score 1):

Go to properties of the list view which contains the messages aligned, See VerticalContentAlignment set it to bottom.
[image: VerticalContentAlignment of the listview]

or add the following code:

```
<ListView x:Name="chatView" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="370" SelectionMode="None" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,46,15,52" Loaded="chatView_Loaded" Height="542" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0,10,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="370">
                <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="{Binding align}" Width="250" Background="#FF007ACC">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="msg" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding msg}" FontSize="22.667">
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it outside the list. Your xaml should be like this:

```
<Grid>
  <ListView Margin="0 0 0 80"/> -- messages, with a bottom border so it doesn't overlap the textbox
  <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="80"/> -- here you type your message
</Grid>
```